# C++ can't initialize a pointer in a pair to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, null, std-pair

I'm compiling with g++ 4.4.7 (and can't go any higher currently), and using the `-std=gnu++0x` compiler switch, which should allow the syntax of the third line.

```
typedef std::vector<CI_RecordInfo_Pair>   CI_RecordInfo_Vector;
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, CI_RecordInfo_Vector*> > MgrBlks;
MgrBlks mgr_n_blks { {"T2M_NAME", NULL} };  // <--- line 59
```

However, the compiler complains as follows:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h: In constructor 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&) [with _U1 = const char (&)[9], _U2 = long int, _T1 = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _T2 = CI_RecordInfo_Vector*]':
tom.cpp:59:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:90: error: invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'CI_RecordInfo_Vector*'
```

I assume the "long int" is the NULL, and that for some reason I'm unable to convert it to a pointer.  Yet elsewhere in a map of structs, I was able to compile something like

```
foo["X"] = { NULL, "bar", 12 }; // first element is a pointer
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Does using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` work?

Comment: It's not supported by g++ 4.4.  Not till 4.6.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler is correct to reject this line:

```
MgrBlks mgr_n_blks { {"T2M_NAME", NULL} };
```

In C++11 `std::pair` has a template constructor that takes any argument types, then converts them to the members:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
  pair(X&& x, Y&& y)
  : first(std::forward<X>(x)), second(std::forward<Y>(y))
  { }
```

`NULL` must be defined as `0` or `0L` or something similar, so template argument deduction deduces the constructor's template arguments as `const char*` and (with GCC) `long`.  The first argument type is convertible to `std::string` but `long` is not convertible to `CI_RecordInfo_Vector*`, so the constructor cannot be called.

For the other case with a map of structs there is no argument deduction, the RHS of the assignment must be convertible to the struct type, and in that case `NULL` is used to directly initialize the struct's first member, rather than first being deduced as a `long` and initializing a `long`, which cannot be converted to a pointer.

Do not use `NULL` in C++11, `nullptr` was invented to avoid exactly these problems, you should use it.

A possible workaround would be to cast the argument to the right type:

```
MgrBlks mgr_n_blks { {"T2M_NAME", (CI_RecordInfo_Vector*)NULL} };
```

but it's simpler and clearer just to use `nullptr`.

Comment: If `NULL` is defined as `0`, then it's of type `int`, not `long`. Apparently the implementation defines `NULL` as `0L` or something similar. With g++ 4.7.2, `NULL` expands to `__null`, which apparently is of type `long`.

Comment: nullptr wasn't added until g++ 4.6, but casting NULL compiles correctly.

Comment: @Chap roll-your-own `nullptr` can also be done -- don't call it `nullptr`, but you can get most of the benefits without much cost.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I said _"`NULL` is defined a `0` or `0L` or similar"_.  I thought it was obvious that it wouldn't be deduced as `long` in all cases, but I'll clarify it. Obviously for GCC it is deduced as `long`, but that isn't required by the standard.

Comment: Your answer seemed to imply that `0` would resolve to `long`; you recent edit fixes that.