# Returning NULL pointer, invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'Object*'

Tags: c++, gcc

My problem seems somewhat similar to [Conversion from null-integer to pointer in comma list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637130/conversion-from-null-integer-to-pointer-in-comma-list)

Here is a minimal example

```
#include <utility>

struct Object {
  double foo;
};

std::pair<Object*,int> test_function() {
  typedef std::pair<Object*,int>  pair_t;
  return pair_t(NULL, 2);
}
// test.cc
```

With gcc 4.4.7, `g++ -std=c++0x -c test.cc -o test.o` fails with

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:90: error: invalid conversion from \u2018long int\u2019 to \u2018Object*

It does compile if I omit `-std=c++0x`. Also, if I use newer versions of gcc, the compilation is fine. Is there anything wrong with the code? Should one expect such differences in gcc versions?

A later edit: I can also return `pair_t((Object*)NULL, 2)`

Comment: Do you heve a specific reason to use `NULL` instead of `nullptr` in post c++11 code? Also, gcc 4.4.7 is *extremely* old, I suggest you upgrade your compiler since that code works flawlessly on a modern compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a01d03ae16e6c3bf

Comment: It may be a bug.  FWIW if you are using C++11 you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: I admit my ignorance of `nullptr`. The code was not originally written for C++11, but I have changed another part of it to include a library that needs C++11.

Comment: Although gcc 4.6.0+ is needed for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756473/what-header-file-needs-to-be-included-for-using-nullptr-in-g

Comment: @Fatih BAKIR, I run into other issues with this code with newer gcc versions. I am not the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is here:

[C++ can't initialize a pointer in a pair to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217221/c-cant-initialize-a-pointer-in-a-pair-to-null)

The NULL is represented as a long by gcc and it cannot be converted to type Object* without the explicit cast.